# Log issue of Solr on jboss

Tags: jboss, log4j, solr, logging

Hye Everybody

I faced a problem when deploying **solr** on **jboss**. I wanted to log the messages  for solr on jboss into a separate file like solr.log instead of appearing in console or server.log. So I tried by making changes in **jboss-log4j.xml** and added following configuration into it.

*<appender name="SOLR"  class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/solr.log"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
</appender>


<category name="org.apache.solr" additivity="false">
    <priority value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SOLR"/>
</category>*

but still getting solr's log in console and server.log and not in solr.log I tried without the **additivity** parameter too but had no luck. The solr using **sl4j** (cotaining sl4j.jar) for logging and **jboss AS 4.2** is using log4j as its using a log4j xml for settings. Please suggest what can be possible solution for this or comment for more info. Thanks in advance.

regards

la89ondevg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slf4j is a logging facade, meaning that it doesn't actually write any logs. It can be configured to use log4j for logging, by adding the [slf4j-log4j jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar) (assuming you're using log4j 1.2.xx) and removing the slf4j-jdk14 jar from the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

I'm assuming your application server will expose the log4j classes to the solr webapp -- if that is not the case, then you will also need to add a [log4j jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar) to the solr `WEB-INF/lib` directory.